# a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token C++

Tags: c++

I genuinely have no idea what to do with this code to be honest. Im trying to finish a school project, but i have no idea how to do it.

Im trying to make a code thats gonna delete and change data in a phone book, but i cannot get it to work.

I tried removing void, but its not working.

I genuinely have no idea what to do with this code to be honest. Im trying to finish a school project, but i have no idea how to do it.

Im trying to make a code thats gonna delete and change data in a phone book, but i cannot get it to work.

I tried removing void, but its not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int brojElemenata()
{
    int a=0;
    string line;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("t-ime.txt");
    if(file.is_open())
        while(!file.eof())
        {
            getline(file,line);
            a++;
        }
    --a;
    file.close();

    return (a/3);
}

void izmenaPodataka()
{
    ifstream tel_ime,tel_telefon;
    ofstream tel_ime_txt,tel_telefon_txt;
    int id,id1;
    string ime,prezime,brTel;

    cout<<"Unesi korisnika: "<<endl;
    cin>>id1;

    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");
    tel_ime_txt.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt.open("2.txt");
    for(int i=0; brojElemenata()>=i ; i++)
    {
        while(!tel_ime.eof())
        {
            tel_ime>>id;
            tel_ime>>ime;
            tel_ime>>prezime;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        while(!tel_telefon.eof())
        {
            tel_telefon>>id;
            tel_telefon>>brTel;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        if(id!=id1)
        {
            tel_ime_txt << id << "\n" << ime << "\n" << prezime << endl;
            tel_telefon_txt << id << "\n" << brTel << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"\tUnesi ime korisnika: ";
            cin>>ime;
            cout<<"\tUnesi prezime korisnika: ";
            cin>>prezime;
            cout<<"\tUnesi broj telefona: ";
            cin>>brTel;

            tel_ime_txt<<id<<"\n"<<ime<<"\n"<<prezime<<"\n";
            tel_telefon_txt<<id<<"\n"<<brTel<<"\n";
        }

    tel_ime.close();
    tel_telefon.close();
    tel_ime_txt.close();
    tel_telefon_txt.close();

    ofstream tel_ime_o,tel_telefon_o;
    tel_ime_o.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon_o.open("tel-telefon.txt");

    ifstream tel_ime_txt_i,tel_telefon_txt_i;
    tel_ime_txt_i.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt_i.open("2.txt");

    while(!tel_ime_o.eof())
    {
        tel_ime_txt_i>>id;
        tel_ime_txt_i>>ime;
        tel_ime_txt_i>>prezime;

        tel_ime_o<<id;
        tel_ime_o<<ime;
        tel_ime_o<<prezime;
    }
    while(!tel_telefon_o.eof())
    {
        tel_telefon_txt_i>>id;
        tel_telefon_txt_i>>brTel;

        tel_telefon_o<<id;
        tel_telefon_o<<brTel;
    }
}

void uklanjanjePodataka()
{
    ifstream tel_ime,tel_telefon;
    ofstream tel_ime_txt,tel_telefon_txt;
    int id,id1,brojac=0;
    string ime,prezime,brTel;

    cout<<"Unesi korisnika: "<<endl;
    cin>>id1;

    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");
    tel_ime_txt.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt.open("2.txt");
    for(int i=0; brojElemenata()>i ; i++)
    {
        while(!tel_ime.eof())
        {
            tel_ime>>id;
            tel_ime>>ime;
            tel_ime>>prezime;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        while(!tel_telefon.eof())
        {
            tel_telefon>>id;
            tel_telefon>>brTel;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        if(id!=id1)
        {
            tel_ime_txt << brojac << "\n" << ime << "\n" << prezime << endl;
            tel_telefon_txt << brojac << "\n" << brTel << endl;
            brojac++;
        }
    }

    tel_ime.close();
    tel_telefon.close();
    tel_ime_txt.close();
    tel_telefon_txt.close();

    ofstream tel_ime_o,tel_telefon_o;
    tel_ime_o.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon_o.open("tel-telefon.txt");

    ifstream tel_ime_txt_i,tel_telefon_txt_i;
    tel_ime_txt_i.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt_i.open("2.txt");

    while(!tel_ime_o.eof())
    {
        tel_ime_txt_i>>id;
        tel_ime_txt_i>>ime;
        tel_ime_txt_i>>prezime;

        tel_ime_o<<id;
        tel_ime_o<<ime;
        tel_ime_o<<prezime;
    }
    while(!tel_telefon_o.eof())
    {
        tel_telefon_txt_i>>id;
        tel_telefon_txt_i>>brTel;

        tel_telefon_o<<id;
        tel_telefon_o<<brTel;
    }
}

void ispisPodataka()
{
    ifstream tel_ime, tel_telefon;
    int id;
    string ime,prezime,brTel;
    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");

    for(int i=0; brojElemenata()>i ; i++)
    {
        while(!tel_ime.eof())
        {
            tel_ime>>id;
            tel_ime>>ime;
            tel_ime>>prezime;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        while(!tel_telefon.eof())
        {
            tel_telefon>>id;
            tel_telefon>>brTel;
            if(id==i)
                break;
        }

        cout<<"\n\tID: "<<id<<"\n\tIme: "<<ime<<"\n\tPrezime: "<<prezime<<"\n\tTelefon"<<brTel<<endl;
    }
    tel_ime.close();
    tel_telefon.close();
}
int main()
{
    int a;
    bool exit=false;
    do
    {
        cout << "\n\tTelenor Srbija";
        cout << "\n\n\t[1] Izmena korisnika";
        cout << "\n\t[2] Uklanjanje korisnika";
        cout << "\n\t[3] Exit";
        cout << "\n\n\tOdabir: ";
        cin >> a;
        switch(a)
        {
        case 1:
            izmenaPodataka();
            break;
        case 2:
            uklanjanjePodataka();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit=true;
            cout << "\n\tDovidjenja!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    while(exit!=true);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: The text editor you are using to write your code should have an automatic function that logically indents all code. If you use it, the problem will be very clear: you forgot a closing brace earlier.

Comment: `izmenaPodataka` is missing its closing brace.

Comment: What @Quimby said. Use a formatting tool, like `clang-format`, and things like this will be found in an instance.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Paste your code [here](http://format.krzaq.cc/) and see how the indentation changes.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the function bodies of all the functions `uklanjanjePodataka()`, `ispidPodataka()` and `main()` inside `izmenaPodataka()`. You had to define them outside `izmenaPodataka()`.

Here's your restructured code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int brojElemenata() {
    int a = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("t-ime.txt");
    if (file.is_open())
        while (!file.eof()) {
            getline(file, line);
            a++;
        }
        --a;
    file.close();

    return (a / 3);
}

void izmenaPodataka() {
    ifstream tel_ime, tel_telefon;
    ofstream tel_ime_txt, tel_telefon_txt;
    int id, id1;
    string ime, prezime, brTel;

    cout << "Unesi korisnika: " << endl;
    cin >> id1;

    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");
    tel_ime_txt.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt.open("2.txt");
    for (int i = 0; brojElemenata() >= i; i++) {
        while (!tel_ime.eof()) {
            tel_ime >> id;
            tel_ime >> ime;
            tel_ime >> prezime;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        while (!tel_telefon.eof()) {
            tel_telefon >> id;
            tel_telefon >> brTel;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        if (id != id1) {
            tel_ime_txt << id << "\n" << ime << "\n" << prezime << endl;
            tel_telefon_txt << id << "\n" << brTel << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "\tUnesi ime korisnika: ";
            cin >> ime;
            cout << "\tUnesi prezime korisnika: ";
            cin >> prezime;
            cout << "\tUnesi broj telefona: ";
            cin >> brTel;

            tel_ime_txt << id << "\n" << ime << "\n" << prezime << "\n";
            tel_telefon_txt << id << "\n" << brTel << "\n";
        }

        tel_ime.close();
        tel_telefon.close();
        tel_ime_txt.close();
        tel_telefon_txt.close();

        ofstream tel_ime_o, tel_telefon_o;
        tel_ime_o.open("tel-ime.txt");
        tel_telefon_o.open("tel-telefon.txt");

        ifstream tel_ime_txt_i, tel_telefon_txt_i;
        tel_ime_txt_i.open("1.txt");
        tel_telefon_txt_i.open("2.txt");

        while (!tel_ime_o.eof()) {
            tel_ime_txt_i >> id;
            tel_ime_txt_i >> ime;
            tel_ime_txt_i >> prezime;

            tel_ime_o << id;
            tel_ime_o << ime;
            tel_ime_o << prezime;
        }
        while (!tel_telefon_o.eof()) {
            tel_telefon_txt_i >> id;
            tel_telefon_txt_i >> brTel;

            tel_telefon_o << id;
            tel_telefon_o << brTel;
        }
    }
}

void uklanjanjePodataka() {
    ifstream tel_ime, tel_telefon;
    ofstream tel_ime_txt, tel_telefon_txt;
    int id, id1, brojac = 0;
    string ime, prezime, brTel;

    cout << "Unesi korisnika: " << endl;
    cin >> id1;

    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");
    tel_ime_txt.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt.open("2.txt");
    for (int i = 0; brojElemenata() > i; i++) {
        while (!tel_ime.eof()) {
            tel_ime >> id;
            tel_ime >> ime;
            tel_ime >> prezime;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        while (!tel_telefon.eof()) {
            tel_telefon >> id;
            tel_telefon >> brTel;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        if (id != id1) {
            tel_ime_txt << brojac << "\n" << ime << "\n" << prezime << endl;
            tel_telefon_txt << brojac << "\n" << brTel << endl;
            brojac++;
        }
    }

    tel_ime.close();
    tel_telefon.close();
    tel_ime_txt.close();
    tel_telefon_txt.close();

    ofstream tel_ime_o, tel_telefon_o;
    tel_ime_o.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon_o.open("tel-telefon.txt");

    ifstream tel_ime_txt_i, tel_telefon_txt_i;
    tel_ime_txt_i.open("1.txt");
    tel_telefon_txt_i.open("2.txt");

    while (!tel_ime_o.eof()) {
        tel_ime_txt_i >> id;
        tel_ime_txt_i >> ime;
        tel_ime_txt_i >> prezime;

        tel_ime_o << id;
        tel_ime_o << ime;
        tel_ime_o << prezime;
    }
    while (!tel_telefon_o.eof()) {
        tel_telefon_txt_i >> id;
        tel_telefon_txt_i >> brTel;

        tel_telefon_o << id;
        tel_telefon_o << brTel;
    }
}

void ispisPodataka() {
    ifstream tel_ime, tel_telefon;
    int id;
    string ime, prezime, brTel;
    tel_ime.open("tel-ime.txt");
    tel_telefon.open("tel-telefon.txt");

    for (int i = 0; brojElemenata() > i; i++) {
        while (!tel_ime.eof()) {
            tel_ime >> id;
            tel_ime >> ime;
            tel_ime >> prezime;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        while (!tel_telefon.eof()) {
            tel_telefon >> id;
            tel_telefon >> brTel;
            if (id == i)
                break;
        }

        cout << "\n\tID: " << id << "\n\tIme: " << ime << "\n\tPrezime: " << prezime << "\n\tTelefon" << brTel << endl;
    }
    tel_ime.close();
    tel_telefon.close();
}
int main() {
    int a;
    bool exit = false;
    do {
        cout << "\n\tTelenor Srbija";
        cout << "\n\n\t[1] Izmena korisnika";
        cout << "\n\t[2] Uklanjanje korisnika";
        cout << "\n\t[3] Exit";
        cout << "\n\n\tOdabir: ";
        cin >> a;
        switch (a) {
        case 1:
            izmenaPodataka();
            break;
        case 2:
            uklanjanjePodataka();
            break;
        case 3:
            exit = true;
            cout << "\n\tDovidjenja!\n";
            break;
        }
    }
    while (exit != true);
    return 0;
}
```